# numpy assignment with masking

Tags: python, numpy

I am a newbie to Python. During an exercise I am supposed to use a mask to multiply all values below 100 in the following list by 2:

```
a = np.array([230, 10, 284, 39, 76])
```

So I wrote the following code:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([230, 10, 284, 39, 76])
cut = 100
a[a < cut] = a*2
```

This results in the following error:
IndexError: index 230 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5

This is confusing since to my understanding, the `a` in `[a < cut]` actually refers to each value in array `a`, but the `a` in `a*2` refers to the whole array.

How can I correct this code using the masking method, instead of using a loop?

Comment: You can view a * 2 as multiplication with each value in array as well, making it consistent.

Comment: That code did not produce the reported error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want, if you want to assign to places where `a < cut` holds (`a < cut = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]` is the boolean index), when you assign to `a[a < cut]`, you assign to the places where the element is 1, meaning on the right side it expects a numpy array of size 3 (or of course one number). You can do this

```
In [1]: a = np.array([230, 10, 284, 39, 76])

In [2]: a[a < cut] = 999

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([230, 999, 284, 999, 999])
```

Or

```
In [1]: a = np.array([230, 10, 284, 39, 76])

In [2]: a[a < cut] = a[a < cut] * 2

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([230,  20, 284,  78, 152])
```

To multiply the selected elements by 2.

Comment: or shorter: `a[a < cut] *= 2`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, once the mask is defined, you can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`numpy.putmask`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.putmask.html)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([230, 10, 284, 39, 76])
cut = 100
mask = a < cut # defines the mask
```

The first does't change the original array:

```
res = np.where(mask, a*2,a)
a #=> [230  10 284  39  76]
res #=> [230  20 284  78 152]
```

The second modifies the original array:

```
np.putmask(a, mask, a*2)
a #=> [230  20 284  78 152]
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out

Comment: Be aware that `np.where()` will evaluate both true and false values regardless of the mask. For large datasets this may be unexpected and suboptimal.

Answer (score 1):

Almost got it right;

```
a[a < cut] *= 2
```

It will perform the operation in-place, you are multiplying whole `a` array by two and trying to "fit it in" the a < cut space (not possible as numpy has array of fixed size after creating).

Answer (score 0):

Your error looks like was produce by `a[a]` not `a[a<cut]`:

```
In [508]: a[a]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-508-bcb5f2cb8e92> in <module>()
----> 1 a[a]

IndexError: index 230 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5
```

But to look at the intended assignment:

```
In [497]: a = np.array([230, 10, 284, 39, 76])
In [498]: mask = a<100
In [499]: mask
Out[499]: array([False,  True, False,  True,  True])
```

So the `mask` selects 3 out of the 5 elements of `a`:

```
In [500]: a[mask]
Out[500]: array([10, 39, 76])
```

`a*2` multiplies all elements of `a`, producing a 5 element array

```
In [501]: a*2
Out[501]: array([460,  20, 568,  78, 152])
```

matching the two is bound to get some sort of error; I get:

```
In [502]: a[mask] = a*2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-502-3df3d7d2d307> in <module>()
----> 1 a[mask] = a*2

ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 5 input values to the 3 output values where the mask is true
```

But if I apply the mask on the right hand side as well:

```
In [503]: a[mask] = a[mask]*2
In [504]: a
Out[504]: array([230,  20, 284,  78, 152])
```

But *= makes the inplace multiplication even easier.

```
In [506]: a[mask] *= 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was very helpful!